# Setting a default selection for an NSPopupButton?

Tags: cocoa, default, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

Is it possible to set a default selection on an NSPopupButton? I have one that allows the user to select the type of server they want to set up, but since an NSPopupButton always shows the first item, they may ignore it if that's the type they want. However, even though that item is being displayed, calling -selectedItem returns (null). Everything works fine if the user picks an item from the menu first.

The Button's content and contentValues are bound to the same Array Controller, which in turn is bound to the keys property of an NSDictionary. I've tried binding the selectedIndex to a variable in the controller and updating that in code, but it has no effect. (I may just be binding it wrong...) How can I select the first item by default?

Thanks in advance!
SphereCat1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bindings, you don't need to and shouldn't get any model info—neither the model itself nor selection state—from the views directly. Talk to the controller that owns the model and the selected indexes.

Note that “index” doesn't have any meaning for an NSDictionary, and `keys` is not a property of an NSDictionary. (Indeed, I would not be surprised if you were to get an exception because your dictionary does not have an object for the key “keys” in it.) It is a method, and not the accessor kind, so while you *can* ask the dictionary for the value of that method using Key-Value Coding, you should not.

What you should do is make [model objects](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/) representing the server types, and hold an array of those, and bind the array controller's content to the property whose value is that array. Bind the pop-up button's `contentValues` to a name property of your model objects, which should hold the localized name of each server type.